# Best way to echo two rows of two?

Tags: php, html, css

I am retrievieng from a query 4 rows.

This rows recover the id (to set the `href`), the image path and the title.

For example the code for the first row is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
 <a href="id">
  <img src="file">
   <p class="titulo-noticia">The title</p>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="col">
 <a href="id">
  <img src="file">
   <p class="titulo-noticia">Another title</p>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I achieve this using:

```
echo "<div class='table'>"
 for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
  echo "<div class='row'>"
  for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){
   echo "<div class='col'>"
   echo "<a href='id'>
      <img src='file'>
       <p class='titulo-noticia'>".$title."</p>
     </a>"
   echo "</div>"
  } //end col loop
  echo "</div>"
 } //end row loop
echo "</div>"
```

CSS is:

```
.col{
    display: table-cell;
}

.row{
    display: row;
}
.table{
    display: table;

}
```

Is this the correct way to show a 2*2 matrix of php content? Or there is a better way using  css?

Thank you.

Comment: correct? does it work, if so then yes

Comment: this has a major error in the fact that both loops use `$i`,  make the second one use `$j`

Comment: You can't create two rows with your code. The inner for loop's `$i` is overwriting the outer loop's `$i`. `row` isn't a valid value for `display`.

Comment: That double $i was a mistake :) Edited.

Comment: you have parse errors unless that pseudo-code. So, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's really a *best way*, but here's another way with CSS. Basically just echo out all your query results into one container div without worrying about rows. Display each result in a div with `float: left` and `width: 50%` and they'll make their own rows.

```
<div class="matrix">
    <?php while ($row = however_youre_fetching_them()): ?>
        <div class="cell">
            <a href="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                <img src="<?= $row['path'] ?>">
                <p><?= $row['title'] ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.cell {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Setting a constant height on the cells should ensure that the rows line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You over-complicating this.

You need to do it by chunks, `array_chunk()` perfect for that:

```
foreach(array_chunk($array, 2) as $chunks){
   //<div class="row">
   foreach($chunk as $chunk){
       //<div class="col"></div>
   }
   //</div>
}
```